# search entire table through a term

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a following table, on which search is performed. when i type "first title" in search bar i get the result. But i wish that if i type just the term "first" then all the rows wherever "first" term is present should get displayed in result. In the given case, first, second and fourth row should get dispalyed as a result. can anyone tell how to do so

table

```
id  title        value
1   first title  Robert
2   second       Max first value                        
3   third        Dean                               
4   first value  Sam
```

**Code for search**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".search").on("submit", function() {
        var value = $("#search", this).val();

        $.post("search.php", {
            value: value
        }, function(data) {
             $("#actionresult").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<form class="search">
    <input type="text" name="term" id="search">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

**search.php**

```
$value=$_REQUEST['value'];
$sqlblog="SELECT * from `tablename` where title='".$value."'";
$resultblog = mysqli_query($con, $sqlblog);
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultblog)>0)
    {
        while($rowblog = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultblog))
            {
                //display value
            }
    }
```

Comment: LIKE query may solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said in the question that **first, second and fourth row should get displayed**, you will have to use `LIKE` clause along with multiple `WHERE` using `OR`. Check following query:

```
    $value=$_REQUEST['value'];
    $sqlblog="SELECT * from `tablename` where title like '%".$value."%' 
              or value like '%".$value."%' ";
    $resultblog = mysqli_query($con, $sqlblog);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultblog)>0)
        {
            while($rowblog = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultblog))
                {
                    //display value
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlblog="SELECT * from `tablename` where title LIKE '%".$value."%'";

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%VALUE%';
```